# Why do my Tweets not appear on my followers timelines?

Tags: twitter

Why do my Tweets not appear on my followers' timelines - I just wrote a plain sentence (without any @ mentions or hashtags) and tweeted it. Should it not appear on my followers timelines?

I need to know if I tweet a simple sentence if it should appear on my followers' timelines because my tweets have not. I am not using some protected tweets or anything like that.

Is there anyone who I can contact for one on one help/support regarding this issue?

Comment: It must appear. Did you check it from web? How do you know it's not appearing? Is it happening for all followers or just one follower?

Comment: Yes I did check it from the web. I checked some of my followers timelines and I do not see the sentence I typed on any of them - since I was new to twitter thought that I may have got it wrong that's why I put up the question here.

Comment: No, its not ok to post you email id here. You can contact Twitter @Support. From here we will try to help you if we can.